# All async widgets return null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

in practice I have a file with various async functions, which I then recall in other files, this is the complete code page :

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cron/cron.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();


abstract class BaseAuth {

  Future<void> NumberGenerator();

  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password);

  Future<String> signUp(String email, String password);

  Future<User> getCurrentUser();

  Future<void> sendEmailVerification();

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever1();

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever2();

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever3();

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever4();

  Future<void> signOut();

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> retrieveScore();

  Future<bool> isEmailVerified();

  Future<String> signInWithGoogle();

}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  int missionNumber1;
  int missionNumber2;
  int missionNumber3;
  int missionNumber4;


  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever1() async{
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("1")
        .get();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever2() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("2")
        .get();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever3() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("3")
        .get();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever4() async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("4")
        .get();
  }

  Future<void> NumberGenerator() {
    final cron= Cron();
    cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('*0**1'), () async { //Tutti i Lunedì alle 00;
      Random random = new Random();
      missionNumber1 = random.nextInt(10);
      missionNumber2 = random.nextInt(10);
      missionNumber3 = random.nextInt(10);
      missionNumber4 = random.nextInt(10);
    });
  }

  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> retrieveScore() async{
    var firebaseUser =  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("leaderboard").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();
  }

  Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    createRecord();
    createLeaderboardPosition();
    User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }


  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return user;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
      await googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  Future<void> sendEmailVerification() async {
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    user.sendEmailVerification();
  }


  Future<bool> isEmailVerified() async {
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    //return user.isEmailVerified();
  }


  void createRecord() async {
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    await databaseReference.collection("user")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
    .set({
      'Nome' : '',
      'Nick' : '',
      'Mail' : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email,
      'Classe' : '',
      'Money' : '',
    });
  }

  void createLeaderboardPosition() async {
    User user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    await databaseReference.collection("leaderboard")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .set({
      'Nick' : '',
      'Score' : '0'
    });
  }




  Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async{
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final UserCredential authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final User user = authResult.user;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser =  _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    createRecord();
    createLeaderboardPosition();
    return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
  }



}
```

In practice, on the page where I use all these async functions by pressing a button I open the **WalkPage** page in this way :

```
InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WalkPage(),
                            ));
```

But just when you open WalkPage all the async widgets that used to work now return null.

This is the WalkPage complete code :

```
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:goodgoals_android/pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:goodgoals_android/services/asyncservice.dart';
import 'package:step_progress_indicator/step_progress_indicator.dart';

class WalkPage extends StatefulWidget {
  WalkPage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.logoutCallback, this.profile})
      : super(key: key);

  final Auth auth;
  final VoidCallback logoutCallback;
  final String userId;
  final ProfilePage profile;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _WalkPageState();
}

class _WalkPageState extends State<WalkPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncMethod();
  }

  void asyncMethod() async {
    await getMissionInfo();
    await widget.auth.MissionRetriever1();
  }

  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List<String> MissionData = [];

  Future<void> getMissionInfo() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await widget.auth.MissionRetriever1();
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snap.data();
    setState(() {
      MissionData.add(data['Q_Category']);
      MissionData.add(data['Q_Name']);
      MissionData.add(data['Q_Description']);
      MissionData.add(data['Q_Score']);
      MissionData.add(data['Q_Target']);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _showForm(),
          ]
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _showForm() {
    return new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0.h, horizontal: 0.0.h),
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new ListView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              showBackButton(),
              showIMG(),
              showTitleText(),
              showDescription(),
              showProgressIndicator(),
              showButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget showBackButton() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 90.0.w, top: 10),
      child: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded),
          onPressed:()
          {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showIMG(){
    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0.h, 0.0.h, 0.0.h, 0.0.h),
      child: new Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/walk_mission.png")
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showTitleText() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
     new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0.h, horizontal: 1.0.h),
        child: new Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: MissionData.isEmpty ?  "Loading..." : MissionData[0],
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: const Color(0xFF5B6577), fontSize: 30.0.sp),
            ))),
        Spacer(),
        new Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: "0/10",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              color: const Color(0XFF5B6577), fontSize: 18.0.sp),
            )
          )
    ]);
  }

  Widget showDescription() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Text(
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida massa at erat rutrum finibus in sed odio. Praesent molestie leo nunc, ut fringilla urna interdum vitae. Vivamus sollicitudin volutpat nunc, sed semper nisi rutrum eu. In eros elit, fermentum eget rhoncus ac, tincidunt a tellus. Vestibulum aliquam nisi in metus hendrerit, vel consequat tortor lacinia. Praesent gravida neque nunc, eget mollis eros congue sit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.",
          maxLines: 9,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            color: const Color(0XFF5B6577), fontSize: 12.0.sp),
          )
        );
  }

Widget showProgressIndicator() {
    return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0.w),
    child: StepProgressIndicator(
      totalSteps: 10,
      currentStep: 5,
      size: 20,
  roundedEdges: Radius.circular(10),
  selectedColor: Colors.blue,
  unselectedColor: Colors.grey[200],
  ));

}
  Widget showButton() {
    return new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.5.h, horizontal: 6.0.h),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 7.0.h,
          width: double.infinity.w,
          child: new RaisedButton(
            elevation: 8.0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            color: const Color(0XFF6200EE),
            child: new Text("Partecipa",
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0.sp, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed:(){},
          ),
        ));
  }



}
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you initialize Firebase at app start?

Comment: yes, in the main.dart i added this : 'void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}'

Comment: Try to work with futures in `FutureBuilder` widget. You can find an example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: In this case FutureBuilder is useless...i need to save all this data in a List not only display it in a text widget...And why this function work in a lot of file but not in this?

Comment: Just for better readable code at first: you shouldnt use a first uppercase for anything else than types and classes. A list is not a type. Its not wrong but its a little bit confusing to read. Also try to try/catch  errors and make null checks on await things to get a better overview what exactly returns null. :)

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who has the same problem as me, the mistake is in the way you open the page.

Before understanding the problem I did this:

```
onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WalkPage(),
                            ));

                      },
```

But in this way the account information is not passed to the new page, and therefore the firestore instance does not exist, instead you have to do in this way :

```
onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WalkPage(auth: widget.auth),
                            ));

                      },
```